# How can I create a xy line chart with c3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

On the example page http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html I see I can easily create a multiline chart, as columns or rows based.

Though, I cannot find out a simple case covered where I want to build  a line chart from a sequence of xy coordinates, like this:

```
[
    {x:1, y:2},
    {x:2, y:3}
    ...
]
```

I can perform this with NVD3.

Is it possible to build a line chart with xy coordinates for each point of it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just need to tell c3 which of those variables is the 'x' value (we know it's x, but just need to tell c3)

A slight tweak to the example at http://c3js.org/samples/data_json.html shows this in practice:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: [
            {name: 'www.site1.com', upload: 200, download: 200, total: 400, x: 2},
            {name: 'www.site2.com', upload: 100, download: 300, total: 400, x: 3},
            {name: 'www.site3.com', upload: 300, download: 200, total: 500, x: 4},
            {name: 'www.site4.com', upload: 400, download: 100, total: 500, x: 5},
        ],
        keys: {
            x: 'x',
            value: ['upload', 'download'],
        }
    },
});
```

JSFiddle version of above: http://jsfiddle.net/dj27wwef/